# Input field in Table "keeps" edited number in same row while scrolling (JSView)

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I've got a sap.ui.table.Table with Input fields and the table gets the data via JSON which works well. However, if I edit the value in the first row for example, and try to scroll down, the value "stays" in the first row until a different value hits this field. So it basically updates every cell except the edited one while scrolling. After that, I scroll up again to see the value I changed, but this value now has the old value from the load at the beginning again. 
I think something with my binding isn't correct at all, because I haven't seen anything like this yet. I know that tables only update the row contexts but I can't figure out how to do this.

Here is a example: https://jsbin.com/yuvujozide/6/edit?html,console,output

Edit the right "Gates" and scroll, to see how it disappears and edit the left value and scroll to see how the value scrolls with the table.

I tried to remove/set the VisibleRowCount and logged to see if the data gets loaded multiple times but that's not the case.

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
  visibleRowCount: 12,
  selectionMode: sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Single,
  visibleRowCountMode: sap.ui.table.VisibleRowCountMode.Fixed,
  editable: true
});

oModel.setData({ rows: tableRows.value, columns: columnArray });
oTable.setModel(oModel);

var counter = 0;
oTable.bindColumns("/columns", function (sId, oContext) {
  var columnName = columnArray[counter];

  var defaultTemplate = new sap.m.Input({
    value: "{" + columnName + "}"
  }).bindProperty("value", columnName, function (cellValue) {
    return returnRange(this, oTable, cellValue, columnName, counter, dic);
  });

  counter++;
  return new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: columnName,
    template: defaultTemplate,
    flexible: true,
    autoResizable: true,
    width: 'auto',
    multiLabels: [
      new sap.ui.commons.Label({ text: columnName }),
      new sap.ui.commons.Label({ text: dic[Number(counter - 1)].value[0] + " - " + dic[Number(counter - 1)].value[1] })
    ]
  });
});

oTable.bindRows("/rows");
```

As you can see I separated the rowData and columnNames in two arrays:
tableRows and columnArray

The `returnRange` function checks some values and just returns the `cellValue`

I would expect that the Input fields keeps the changed values (which is probably normal), so I can change several Input fields and then I can Update the table via Ajax-Call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `sap.ui.table.Table` has a custom scrolling behaviour that is different from the default browser scrolling. Instead of creating a row for each record, it will create a fixed number of rows and re-bind these rows after each scroll.

If the table is editable and bound to a `JSONModel`, it will usually create a two-way-binding and update the model values upon user input, hence scrolling works fine. But since you have provided a custom formatter function for the binding (`returnRange`), a two-way-binding is not possible anymore. This means that any user input is lost after scrolling.

If you remove the formatter function like this

```
var defaultTemplate = new sap.m.Input({
    value: "{" + columnName + "}"
});
```

it will work fine.

In case you want to validate the user input, you should listen to the input's [`change`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.InputBase/events/change) event and use [`InputBase#setValue`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.InputBase/methods/setValue) to set it to a different value. This will also reflect your changes in the `JSONModel`.

Comment: Thank you, without the formatter it works as expected. If I would like to change the  the color of the Input fields for each cellvalue with `addstyleclass`, is there any easy way to achieve this without a formatter? Because I'm not sure how to get each cellvalue...

Comment: I don't think that that is possible. `sap.ui.table.Table` is really limited when it comes to customizing the cell controls.